# RegEx IP Adress bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, ip-address

in my react app I have a Input that validates if the string is an IPV4 Address or not.

This is my RegEx:

```
^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

Testcases:

**192.168.0.1**

1. In my app: true
2. On some random regex test website: **true**

**192.168.0.**

1. In my app: false
2. On some random regex test website: **false**

**192.168.0**

1. In my app: true
2. On some random regex test website: **false**

**192.168.**

1. In my App: false
2. On some random regex test website: **false**

**192.168**

1. In my app: true
2. On some random regex test website: **false**

i have no clue whats wrong here...
on some random regex test website my regex string seems to work great but in my app it doesnt...

mb one of you knows anything related to this problem...

thanks for your time
david

Comment: So, if it does not work in your *code*, you should provide the *code* in your question.

Comment: How do you use this regex in your app?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/z8otNx/1 only the first example is true?

Comment: your app is wrong - why would you use regexp when there's far easier methods

Comment: i thought it was no needed to post my code because i used an Input Component from a library but turns out... it would habe been better to provide the code... 

i used it like this: const regex = "...\..." and should have used it like this: const regex = "...\\..."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used it like this in my code:

```
const ipAddressValidationRegExString = '^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1?[0-9]?[0-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1?[0-9]?[0-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1?[0-9]?[0-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1?[0-9]?[0-9])$'
```

and the problem was the `\\`

Correct regex:

```
const ipAddressValidationRegExString = '^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1?[0-9]?[0-9])**\\\\**.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1?[0-9]?[0-9])**\\\\**.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1?[0-9]?[0-9])**\\\\**.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1?[0-9]?[0-9])$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget regular expressions. Those are always going to be write-once-read-never again.  Just bang out a helper function using standard parsing stuff:

```
let isInRange = (x, min, max) => {
   return ((x >= min) && (x <= max));
}

let isValidAddress = (addr) => {

    try {
        let parts = addr.split('.');
        let values = [];

        if (parts.length != 4) {
           return false;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
           values[i] = parseInt(parts[i]);
        }

        return (isInRange(values[0], 0, 255) && isInRange(values[1], 0, 255) &&
                isInRange(values[2], 0, 255) && isInRange(values[3], 0, 255));
    }
    catch (err) {
        // any exception throw above => return false
    }
    return false;
}
```